# Making sense out of Android TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR sensor quaternion

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, rotation, android-sensors, quaternions

I am trying to develop an application where I get the rotation of my phone and send it to another application developed on Unity, where I want to rotate a 3D object to match my phone's rotation.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lq_5B-vNGE

The issue I am having is: I cannot make sense out of the quaternion that I get from the android application.

On Unity, when I use the quaternion to rotate my 3D object, the axis are not matching. For example, when I rotate the phone on the Y axis, it rotates the 3D object on the X axis. I have tried to remap the axis to the correct ones but I have been unable to.

This was one of my attempts where I try to transform the quaternion to euler angles, adjust the X, Y, and Z manually and transform it back to quaternions. The result is an ever messier rotation that doesn't make sense to me.

```cs
//This is where I create a quaterion out of the values I get from the android phone
Quaternion myQuaternion = new Quaternion(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, pos.w);

//This is where I transform the quaterions to Euler angles so I can adjust the angles to match the angles they should change
Vector3 myEulerAngles = myQuaternion.eulerAngles;

//This is where I create a new Vector3 trying to remap the angles
Vector3 adjustedEulerAngles = new Vector3(myEulerAngles.z, myEulerAngles.y, myEulerAngles.x); ;

//This is where I transfor the Euler angles back to quaternions
Quaternion newQuaternion = Quaternion.Euler(adjustedEulerAngles);

//This is where I set the location rotation of the object to the "adjusted" quaterion
transform.localRotation = newQuaternion;
```

Do you have any idea on why this code does not work? If not, any good resources where I can understand better how to understand the values the android phone sends me?

This is the code I use on the android phone. These values are the results from a TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR sensor.

```cs
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        orientations[i] = sensorEvent.values[i];
    }
    String temp = String.valueOf(orientations[0]);
    Log.i("STATE", temp);
}
```

I have checked the android documentation on this sensor but it was not very helpful:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR

I have also checked some videos which explain a bit better how rotation works:

https://youtu.be/C7JQ7Rpwn2k?t=35m32s

https://youtu.be/kYOtk5a6_x4

But I still cannot make sense out of the quaternion I have and how to make it correctly to the 3D object.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, and if I did anything wrong creating my post please let me know as this is my first question on stackoverflow. Thank you!

Comment: I have worked with unity3d and quaternions before and I found that working with euler angles was sufficient. Unity3D converts euler angles to quaternions and handles all the rotation itself so no need to mess with the quaternions.

Comment: I have tried to transform the data on the android application to Euler angles and it worked. The problem is that when I use it in Unity I run into the gimbal lock issue and cannot rotate the object 360º in one of the axes. That is why I decided to go for the quaternions as I need 360º of rotation on all axes.

Comment: I read that unity uses quaternions internally. Instead of creating new quaternions you could try something like object.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (object.rotation, Quaternion.Euler (x, y, z), Time.deltaTime);    x, y and z are euler angles.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I can't believe that it has been 3 years and no one helped you